# Как сделать кнопку неактивной?

Tags: android

Мне нужно чтобы кнопка для отправки запроса на сервер была неактивна, пока в EditText не будет нужного количества цифр (от 6 до 9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать простую проверку на кол-во символов. Не знаю на каком языке вы пишете поэтому:

**Java**

```
int length = editText.getText().length();
myButton.setEnabled(length > 6 && length < 9);
```

**Kotlin**

```
val length: Int = editText.getText().length()
myButton.setEnabled(length in 6..9)
```

так же можно добавить слушатель в поле для ввода:

**Java**

```
 ed_caption.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

          myButton.setEnabled(s.length() > 6 && s.length() < 9);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            
        }
    });
```

**Kotlin**

```
 ed_caption.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                myButton.setEnabled(s.length in 7..8)
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
        })
```

Comment: Andrew, спасибо за ответ! Не совсем понимаю почему не работает проверка на кол-во символов, можете взглянуть? https://ideone.com/xodC2R

Comment: а если добавить слушатель для поля ввода, вместо того что вы добавили? или так тоже не работает?

Comment: Сработало, только изначально кнопка активна, пока в поле не начать вводить цифры..

Comment: так делайте ее изначально неактивной) это будет логично мне кажется

Comment: Именно в этом и проблема, не могу понять как это сделать.. Не пинайте сильно, только начал осваивать программирование.

Comment: либо в xml что-то типа enabled свойство, либо в классе в onCreate myButton.setEnabled(false)

Comment: Ещё раз огромное спасибо!